# Using prototype with Jquery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, javascript-framework, conflict

Is there any way of using prototype to coexist with Jquery.

What i mean is not Jquery with prototype with the Jquery NoConflict tag but the other way around.

I have to override prototypes utility methods to coexist with other libraries?

I have no control over the Jquery Scripts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When jQuery is included, it takes a copy of whatever is defined as `$` and stores a reference to it. When you use `jQuery.noConflict` it restores that reference, and returns `jQuery` which allows you to "rename" jQuery.

If you want to rename Prototype, that should be entirely possible.

```
// 1. include Prototype
//    $ == Prototype
// 2. include jQuery
//    $ == jQuery

var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var $p = $;
$ = jq;

// now, $ == jQuery
// and $p == Prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

I just changed every occourence of $ to pType in prototype and dependent libraries

Added them as secondary assets for this use case.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.