# Using Prototype JS on pages that use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, javascript-framework, conflict

I am revamping a website that *now* uses jQuery. The process is more than half way done but for the time being I need to setup a demo as soon as possible. For this I will copy existing ASP code as-is and these particular pages require prototype plugins. Converting all prototype plugins to jQuery is in the todo list. So I am wodering if there is a workaround that I can use in the mean time to have both libraries working on same page. The workaround is temporary, I'll port the plugins to jQuery (or use a jQuery alternate) eventually.

### Edit

OK, so I prefer to stick with $ = jQuery. My revised question is: does prototype have a no conflict option? I can wrap all prototype plugin code inside wrappers, so wondering if it is possible to do a:

```
(function(/* what comes here? */) {
    // some code that uses $ and $$
})(/* what comes here? */);
```

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here: [Using prototype with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089471/using-prototype-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read about [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: I ended up replacing all `$` with `jQuery`... was easy as there were only 20 such instances.